# R how to calculate row wise medians by conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to calculate row wise medians with conditions in R. Anyone knows how can I do it?
Example Data set:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Median
A      x      1
B      x      2
A      y      2
A      y      3
B      x      2
B      x      1
```

For instance, I want to calculate that medians by row wise like Col1 is and Col2 is same with the row.

Comment: I guess you need a group by median i.e. `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(Col1, Col2) %>% mutate(Median = median(Col3)) %>% ungroup`

Comment: We normally would not call this "row-wise".